# Sailsjs - How to package sails application

Tags: node.js, npm, package, sails.js

I'm working on a sails application.

Currently, to move to another server.

I have to go through 3 steps:

**Step1**: Checkout source code.

**Step2**: Run `npm install` to download dependentcy

**Step3**: Deploy sails app by cmd `sails lift --prod`

Is there any way to just push a .zip to server and run cmd deploy?

**My purpose is:**

**Step1**: Zip all to 1 folder

**Step2**: Upzip and deploy

No need to install dependency  manual

Like the way of java distribution > build a war file and put into tomcat

Or Angular CLI compile all to `dist` folder

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Jenkins pipeline and shell scripts to achieve it.

1. Create a jenkins pipeline
2. Build a zip file and push it to some storage. ( Amazon S3? )
3. Execute the shell script to ssh into production server and execute another shell script which downloads the latest build from S3, installs dependency, and then launches the app.

Sample Jenkinsfile:

```
    pipeline {

        agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                checkout scm
                echo 'Zipping..'
                sh 'echo "My-app-`date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S"`.zip" >> buildName.txt'
                sh 'if [ -d .git ]; then echo "Removing git folder"; rm -r .git/ ; fi;'
                sh 'zip -r `cat buildName.txt` .'
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: '*.zip'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo 'test..'
            }
        }
        stage('Upload') {
            steps {
                echo 'uploading..'
                sh 's3cmd put `cat buildName.txt` s3://my-app-builds'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying....'
                sh './deploy_to_production.sh'
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Else you can dockerize the application.